# IIS return 404 error, suspect problem is with RouteConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Locally my solution is working fine, but after deploying the published to the server, it returns 404 error on all my ASPX pages despite the resources are all there. My solution is .NET Framework Web Forms based and I have this RouteConfig.cs file in my App_Start folder. I haven't configured anything in this section yet.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

I can't find IIS log files as it's not self managed, might need to take some time on that.

Comment: enable IIS log and check actual request address in log

Comment: Did you try publish your solution to a local IIS server? If so and the result is the same then you should attach your debugger that particular w3wp process to get more insight.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Peter and Always_a_learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server only support .NET Framework till version 4.61 instead of targeted 4.8 in my projects.